# how to take backup from wiki and import in postgresql?

Tags: xml, postgresql, mediawiki, database-backups

I have to perform backup from wikimedia database and import that data into postgresql. I was googling about it but got no solution.

I am not asking for solution here. All I want is idea that how I can copy data from wikimedia and import the same into postgresql. Of course data will be in xml format.

I know it might be wrong question but what's wrong in try.

Comment: Did you see these links ? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Restoring_a_wiki_from_backup http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki#PostgreSQL

Comment: So far I found  that using `mwdumper.jar` from [here][1] with:
`java -jar mwdumper.jar --format=sql:1.4 acurrentpagesxmldump.bz2 > thesqlcommand.sql` 
and a different output with:
`java -jar mwdumper.jar --format=sql:1.4 acurrentpagesxmldump.bz2 > thesqlcommand5.sql` produces an SQL command, possibly valid for PostgreSQL. Not validate since this requires the creation of tables which I have not created 


  [1]: https://code.google.com/archive/p/wikitrust/downloads

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to import an [XML data dump](//meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) from Wikipedia or some other wiki running MediaWiki, just follow [these instructions](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps) — most of the methods described on that page should work just as well on PostgreSQL as on MySQL.

If you're trying to import an SQL dump file for some reason, you'll need to [convert it from MySQL to PostgreSQL format](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) first.  Note that, if you're simply trying to import content from Wikipedia or another Wikimedia wiki, you shouldn't need to do this — the XML dumps should contain everything you need.

Comment: Your last link is broken.

Comment: Looks like that thread got deleted. Replaced it with a wiki link.